# How to get coco metric for custom dataset on yolov5

Tags: object-detection, yolov5

I trained yolov5 on custom dataset having coco annotation file and got prediction.json file. My question is how I can get coco metric using custom dataset.

Comment: You mean how to calculate the Mean Average Precision (mAP) metric?

Comment: Yes, I mean how we can calculate mAP metric from YOLOv5

Comment: The easiest way to validate your model would be to run a CLI command "python val.py --weights best.pt --data data.yaml --task test" inside yolov5 directory (test data path must be specified in data.yaml) https://docs.ultralytics.com/usage/cli/. But if you want  predictions.json, so in this case you need to compute mAP manually, as in this article https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-average-precision-in-object-detection-localization-algorithms-and-how-to-calculate-it-3f330efe697b for example. I would recommend the CLI option, because it's much easier and faster to do.

Comment: Thanks for your details, Actually I already get those results what I want to do is to get the mAP small, medium and large as we get in coco.